# how current a big(max) Column

Tags: c#

I have an array with random number and i current all the Column in int currentColumn.

now i see all current Column but i want its print only the max Column.

its in c# console.

```
class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int SIZE = 4;

        int[,] Table = new int[SIZE, SIZE];

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            {
                int randnumber = rand.Next(0,100);
                Table[i, j] = randnumber;

                Console.Write(Table[i, j]);
                Console.Write("\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        int max = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            int currentColumn = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            {
                currentColumn = currentColumn + Table[i, j];



            }


            Console.Write();
            Console.Write("\t");

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggesst me a solution?

Comment: What precisely is the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly but if you want to output the largest value, you should re-write the second part of your code like this:

```
    int max = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        int currentColumn = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            currentColumn = currentColumn + Table[i, j];
            if (max < Table[i, j])
            {
                max = Table[i, j];
            }


        }


        Console.Write();
        Console.Write("\t");

    }

    Console.WriteLine("The maximum value for the table is {0}", max);
```

And if you do not need the accumulation that is happening in the currentColumn variable, you need to drop it - it will only slow code execution down (although that will show only for large values of SIZE - definitely above 100 000), not to mention that with large enough values of SIZE, you can overflow the integer type.